# Converting existing code to Span<T>, which method to use?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

Existing code:

```
public class Header {
   public Header(byte[] data)
   {
      // fill up some properties from the data byte[].
      var subdata = new byte[16];
     this.F = new Foo(Array.Copy(data, 0, subdata, 0, 16));
   }

   public Foo F {get; set; }
}
```

Existing code works like this:

```
BinaryReader br = ....
var h = new Header(br.ReadBytes(64));
```

This feels like it could be optimized with Span.

My code now looks like:

```
public class Header {
   public Header(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
   {
      // fill up some properties from the data byte[].
     this.F = new Foo(data.Slice(0, 16));
   }

   public Foo F {get; set; }
}
```

Now, which option should I use and why?

Original code:

```
BinaryReader br = ....
var h = new Header(br.ReadBytes(64));
```

Version 1:

```
BinaryReader br = ....
var h = new Header(br.ReadBytes(64).AsSpan());

// I guess this is the same:
BinaryReader br = ....
Span<byte> buf = br.ReadBytes(64);
var h = new Header(buf);
```

Version 2:

```
BinaryReader br = ....
Span<byte> buffer = new byte[64];
br.Read(buffer);
var h = new Header(buffer);
```

Version 3:

```
BinaryReader br = ....
Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[64];
br.Read(buffer);
var h = new Header(buffer);
```

Version ?: anything else?

Comment: You can not use span. Span is there to "cut out" a view on an array. V2 AND v3 basicaly allocate an array - span is as useless there as anything gets. v1  does nothing except wrapping that array in a span, what do you think you gain?

Comment: gaining performance in the "br.Read()" section and in the Header object where I can use Slice without needing to make an extra copy again when passing to Foo object?

Comment: Nope. As the array is allocated anyway there is no read performance gain. You can always slice out something you want at a later stage for the same overhead. You basically get an array back. Span would allow you to slice something out of the view  - but you do not show ANY code doing any slice. No gain. Even filling up part of the buffer is not a gain - the gain would be reading a part without the receiver being able to see the difference, stuff where you normally would copy. YOu never do that.

Comment: Header class has an example Slice (I added only one to keep the example small, but imagine there are two or more Slice operations in the Header constructor.) The performance gain would be in Header accepting a (ReadOnly)Span instead of byte[]?  but if I understand, version 1, 2 and 3 basically have no effect as I need to create a new array anyway? correct?

Comment: @TomTom note v3 does not allocate an array

Comment: Actaually it does - on stack, but still an array.